# Swift unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am following this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9NhYx9xIiU&t=838s see at 14:00 and got this crash Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' unrecognized selector sent to instance. This is the code

```
func setUpViews(){
    addSubview(titleLabel)
    addSubview(createButton)

    createButton.addTarget(self, action: "createNotice", for: .touchUpInside)

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[v0]-4-[v1]-4-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(),
                                                  metrics: nil, views: ["v0": titleLabel, "v1": createButton]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-4-[v0]-4-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(),
                                                  metrics: nil, views: ["v0": titleLabel]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-4-[v0]-4-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(),
                                                  metrics: nil, views: ["v0": createButton]))
}

func createNotice(){
    print("tapped");
}
```

I tried many solutions from stackoverflow like

```
createButton.addTarget(self, action: "createNotice:", for: .touchUpInside)// adding semicolon 

func createNotice(_ sender: UIButton){
    print("tapped");
}
```

but the problem is not fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this

```
createButton.addTarget(self, action: "createNotice:", for: .touchUpInside)// adding semicolon
```

use

```
createButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(createNotice(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)// adding semicolon
```

//

```
@objc func createNotice(_ sender: UIButton){
  print("tapped")
}
```

Comment: yup worked! although i had to add @objc to my func.  Thanks btw :-)